# Does anyone know why this trigger is not working?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER SetNapomena
BEFORE INSERT
ON stavkafakture
FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        V_napomena VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER zabranjeno DISABLE';

    SELECT napomena INTO V_napomena
    FROM faktura
    WHERE brojfakture =:NEW.brojfakture;

    :NEW.napomena := V_napomena;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER zabranjeno ENABLE';
END;
```

When I insert into a table (in this case stavkafakture) I get this error:

> Cannot commit in a trigger

I did some research and added Pragma Autonomous Transaction and commit, but after adding them I try to insert a row in the table it loads forever and never works.
It stays in load forever.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I don't think oracle allow DDL in trigger, you should do this in proper pl/sql procdure though.

Comment: You cannot issue DDL commands as part of a DML transaction, whether directly in the trigger or in a stored procedure, as it forces an implicit commit. That said, what is the purpose of disabling a trigger before a select statement, then re-enabling it immediately? The select statement would not cause the trigger to fire, i wouldn't think.

Comment: In oracle, you can issue DDL in pl/sql stored procedure, but I think there is some limitation...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It looks that you'd want to *workaround* something that - possibly - can be done differently, in a supported & allowed manner.

Comment: @Littlefoot maybe yes, i have 2 tables "ta" and "tb" and two triggers, first trigger prevent the update and insert in a column of "tb". The second trigger updates that column that you cant insert or update. Thats why im trying to disable and then enable the trigger after the it inserts. I dont want to give user the permission to change the value of the column bcz the value as to be the same as "ta" in the same column callled "napomena".

Comment: It would be clearer if you explained your business logic using the tables named in the trigger(`stavkafakture`,`faktura`) rather than `ta`, `tb`. Also, it seems like this problem is a failure of the data model: in a properly normalised model there would be no need to duplicate and synchronise `napomena` on both tables. Finally,  I still don't understand what code you have in trigger `zabranjeno` which means you need to disable it in trigger `SetNapomena`. In short, unless you **fully explain** your scenario we are not going to be able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle DDL statement like CREATE, ALTER, DROP generate an explicit commit.

IE if you issue this kind of statement this does not requires a COMMIT nor a ROLLBACK :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(MyField NUMBER);
```

This will create the `MyTable` table and cannot be ROLLBACK.
This is a limitation of Oracle that other RDBMS like PostreSQL doesn't have.